# How to make jswing components remember its status after closing it

Tags: java, swing, persistence

For example, if I had checked a JCheckBox when I opened the program, how would I make the it remember the status of the checkbox so that the next time I open up the JFrame, the box stays checked.

I would also like to extend this question to other swing components like radiobuttons, color chooser, etc.

Attempted solution: The only way I can think of it is possibly making a new file so that the program can update and read the status of it and adjust the swing components when opened. However, this is too inefficient. I read online something about cookies but I am not too sure.

Comment: [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Comment: [`Preferences`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)